# AWS Elastic Compute Cloud EC2 pricing issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-ec2

| **Description** | **Usage Quantity** | **Amount in USD** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud T4GCPUCredits |  | USD 10.90 |
| ↳ $0.04 per vCPU-Hour of T4G CPU Credits | 272.513 vCPU-Hours | USD 10.90 |

Can anyone tell me what is this pricing and how can I reduce this cost? I'm on the free tier and I like to keep it that way. Also, I don't want to terminate my current EC2 instance.